# destructor is not being called after object goes out of scope

Tags: c++

Consider this example :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    ~MyClass() { cout << "DTOR OK !" << endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
    MyClass test();
    MyClass* pTest = new MyClass();
    delete pTest;
}
```

Why "DTOR OK !" is not printed twice ? why the destructor of the local object "test" is not called ?

When the destructor is private, I've noticed that there is only a compile error for delete pTest; but not for the local object ? what's happening here ?

Comment: OK. So it's the Most. I couldn't remember if it was most or non-most when I went dupe hunting.

Comment: It is OK, since the constructor is not called either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line actually declares a function, not a variable.

```
MyClass test();
```

If you were to change to uniform initialization syntax, you'd see two destuctor calls

```
MyClass test{};
```

or

```
auto test = MyClass();
```

Comment: For completeness, this is called the "Most Vexing Parse." Might be good to note that so that the OP can search it later on. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef This is not the most vexing parse

Comment: OK, I thought that we can't put function prototypes inside main(), but apparently we can't only put the implementation...

Comment: @Aminos *OK, I thought that we can't put function prototypes inside main()* -- FYI, this has existed since good old `C`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was under the impression that the Most Vexing Parse was the general term for "a statement that looks like a variable declaration but actually is a function declaration." Is that incorrect? I'm happy to be corrected!

Answer (score 2):

"MyClass test();" - you wanted to write `MyClass test;` - you are not creating an object, you are declaring a function "test" that takes no arguments and returns a "MyClass".